# ng-select to pass the same event like select

Tags: angular, typescript, events, angular-ngselect

I have a running code that contains a drop-down select options, that fires up a function onChange... like the following...

```
<select (change)="doSomething($event)" name="" value="">
    <option> --Select Item-- </option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of itemsList" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.value}}</option>
</select>
```

in doSomething(event), I'm receiving the event as a full node object like

```
{
  isTrusted: true,
  target: ...,
  ...
  ...
  path: (..),
  target: ..,
  timeStamp: ..
}
```

Now I'm replacing the *select* with *ng-select* for more wanted functionality... but I can't mimic the event output structure.

```
<ng-select [items]="itemsList" bindLabel="value" bindValue="id" (change)="doSomething($event)">
</ng-select>
```

now what I'm getting as the event is simply

```
{
  id: 101,
  value: "First Selection Item"
}
```

Is there a way that I can get a whole event object out of ng-select, as I'm getting from select?

Comment: Looking at the code, not like that. `change` returns `NgOption`, which is declared as part of the package. You could potentially do something with template refs and/or viewchild. As there a specific reason to having the whole event object though?

Comment: There's a huge component that's build around that event & different flags being checked all over the place.. changing the logic of it would be a huge amount of work on core logic.

not sure I understand what you mean by using template refs, though!

Comment: Forget about that. I meant using `#option1` (template ref variables) on the options and passing those, but of course that would only be a part of the native event. I don't think you can get the native event from the ngSelect. You will have to either change some surround logic, build a custom select component that fits your needs. (You can extend the parameter list of your event handler and pass in more than $event, but I don't think you can get the required values in the template to actually pass them.)